# External Plugins in React

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, plugins, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a react UI and i want it to support plugins/hooks

i need a way to load external components from window or JS file and let them render inside project components, disable/enable/replace components.

something like creating items in menus, creating views, change/add inputs, etc.

the external components would be loaded from window and it would have access to the app state, called on render functions, etc

I am thinking in something like WordPress hooks, but i can't reach it in React.

example:

```
<Component>
 {doAction('HOOK_BEFORE_RENDER')}
</Component>
```

The example is just for illustration. Any better approach would be great.

in `doAction`, the plugin would be able to block or change the rendering of a component, add content, like fields on form and change application state and logic.